# sktime ARIMA invalid frequency

Tags: python, time-series, series, arima, sktime

I try to fit ARIMA model from sktime package. I import some dataset and convert it to pandas series. Then I fit the model on the train sample and when I try to predict the error occurs.

```
from sktime.forecasting.base import ForecastingHorizon
from sktime.forecasting.model_selection import temporal_train_test_split
from sktime.forecasting.arima import ARIMA
import numpy as np, pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/selva86/datasets/master/a10.csv',
                 parse_dates=['date']).set_index('date').T.iloc[0]
p, d, q = 3, 1, 2
y_train, y_test = temporal_train_test_split(df, test_size=24)
model = ARIMA((p, d, q))
results = model.fit(y_train)
fh = ForecastingHorizon(y_test.index, is_relative=False,)

# the error is here !!
y_pred_vals, y_pred_int = results.predict(fh, return_pred_int=True)
```

The error message is the following:

```
ValueError: Invalid frequency. Please select a frequency that can be converted to a regular
`pd.PeriodIndex`. For other frequencies, basic arithmetic operation to compute durations
currently do not work reliably.
```

I tried to use `.asfreq("M")` while reading the dataset, however, all the values in the series become `NaN`.
What is interesting is that this code works with the default `load_airline` dataset from `sktime.datasets` but not with my dataset from github.

Comment: For reference, as of version 0.5.3, TBATS requires `pd.PeriodIndex` to work. But Prophet requires `pd.DatetimeIndex`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get a different error: ``` ValueError: ``unit`` missing ```, possibly due to version difference. Anyhow, I'd say it is better to have your dataframe's index as `pd.PeriodIndex` instead of `pd.DatetimeIndex`. The former is I think more explicit (e.g. monthly series has its time-steps as periods not exact dates) and works more smoothly. So after reading the csv,

```
df.index = pd.PeriodIndex(df.index, freq="M")
```

should clear the error (it does in my version; 0.5.1):
[image: f]

Comment: After setting index as ```df.index = pd.PeriodIndex(df.index, freq="M")``` I encountered the following error ```DateParseError: day is out of range for month```

Comment: @student Can't reproduce that error. I suspect it is due to `pandas` version; i'm using 1.1.0