# DateParseError error appears when I try to set PeriodIndex

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, period

This continuation of my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66278986/sktime-arima-invalid-frequency).
I try to fit ARIMA model from sktime package but I had a problem. With [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66278986/sktime-arima-invalid-frequency/66291975#66291975) of the answerer, I set period index, but still, errors occur.

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/selva86/datasets/master/a10.csv',
                 parse_dates=['date'])

df.index = pd.PeriodIndex(df.index, freq="M") #ERROR is here
df = df.T.iloc[0]
```

The error message is the following
`DateParseError: day is out of range for month`
Maybe some days are skipped in the dataset, or there is another reason.

Pandas version is '1.2.2'.

Comment: Did you try passing `index_col="date"` to `pd.read_csv`?

Comment: Now it works properly. Thank you once again for your help. Consider editing the answer to the previous post, and I will tick it as answered.